# Online service that allows drawing a circle on top of a map?

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations, map-drawing

I need to draw a circle around a central location to show where other places are within a given distance.

As objects, OSM-based [Umap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/) only supports Marker, Polyline, and Polygon.

Currently, I take a screenshot, add a circle using Paint Shop Pro, and send the resulting JPG, but I'd rather a live map so people can zoom in/out and move around:
[image]

Does someone know of an alternative, preferably with OSM tiles built in, that would also support circle drawing?

Comment: Do you need to offload the whole map function (umap style)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "offload the whole map". Download the map to the user's computer?

Comment: Looks like there's currently no solution that looks like what I had in mind as pictured above. Too bad. Thanks everyone.

Comment: As a workaround, one can always draw a circle-aproximation elsewhere, export it as .gpx file, and show that gpx as a layer in uMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would "Radius Around A Point On A Map" do what you want? You can generate a map URL or download the KML for a given point and radius.

http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the screen is too busy. I was looking for something that would look like the OSM mockup that I built. Oh well.

Comment: Turns out it's the closest tool to draw a circle around a location. Thank you.

Comment: Out of service since 12th July 2018: _Unfortunately, due to a large price increase in back-end services, freemaptools.com can no longer offer map drawing._

Answer (score 3):

You could use [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), an open source JavaScript Library for interactive maps. It supports drawing circles on a webmap using the [circle-class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle). All you need is the geographical point and the radius in meters. You can find a simple example in the [quick start guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a site similar to Umap, ie. ready-to-use with its own servers.

Comment: You should state that in your question more clearly, then. Leaflet does come with OSM as default tiles, though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that means. Installing a whole server just to display a picture is over-kill. Thank you.

Comment: Actually all you need on your server is the Leaflet JavaScript library and some JavaScript code in your html page. Of course, this is a different type of solution than umap, where you don't need anything at all.

Comment: Yes, one only need some place online to publish single `.html` file like https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example-overlays.html (there are hundreds of sites offering such free hostings for such static HTML content - here is random example https://hosthtml.live/p/BBfak). Actually, you might even be able to  just embed that html into e-mail that you send to people, so no hosting needed at all.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use http://geojson.io/?

You can draw your polygons/circle or use QGIS. Free and open source for geospatial software with a web mapping plugin like QGIS2web.

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html
https://www.gislounge.com/a-web-mapping-tutorial-for-beginners/

Then host it anywhere including github pages.

Comment: The Github link you cite is for qgis2leaf, which is no longer developed, and which was merged into qgis2web. qgis2web is at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Google Earth. It provides also a circle measurement tool.

Answer (score 1):

Out of service march 2023: https://jopf.re/osmaps-radius/

[image: Online tool to draw a radius on Openstreetmap tiles]

This jopf.re online tool can draw radius circles in Miles, Kilometers, Feet, Metres, Inches, Yards, Fathoms, Nautical Miles, Chains, Rods and Furlongs.

Source code: https://github.com/jopfre/osmaps-radius

Comment: that website no longer works is 2023/03